# LibreOffice and Firefox interaction

Tags: firefox, libreoffice, dock

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with LibreOffice 6.0.7.3 00m0(Build:3) and Firefox 70.0.1. Whenever I have Firefox (Ubuntu default) opened with LibreOffice Calc (csv), if I have Firefox opened the LibreOffice icon will not show as opened in the favorites bar. Once I close Firefox it shows back again. The weird thing is when both are opened LibreOffice is not showing. I can see it open in Alt+Tab and can open it normally from there.

I tried opening other apps to see if there is a limit in the favorite bar, but it appears the problem is with LibreOffice only.

It is not an urgent matter but I am confused to why this happens.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's weird. I have 18.04 as well, and it doesnt seem to be happening over here.
I have the following versions though, which opens tons of combinations of why you could be experiencing this issue:

Sorry, I know I am not answering your question, but does this help you narrow it down at all?

```
LibreOffice 6.0.7.3 00m0(Build:3)

Mozilla Firefox 70.0.1

Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

ubuntu:GNOME
```

Here's how I checked that stuff, in case you want to check your as well and dont know how:

```
$ firefox -version
Mozilla Firefox 70.0.1

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
ubuntu:GNOME
```

[image: Screenshot of Libre Calc and Firefox both opened at the same time, both showing in favorites bar]

Comment: I can't screenshot while I am in `ALT+TAB` to show you, but I did your commands and I have same output